# MySQL: Set to default value on update

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to set a column to its default value (or any specified value) on update when no value is specifically given in the statement? I was thinking that a trigger might accomplish this. Something like

```
IF ISNULL(NEW.column) THEN
 NEW.column = value
END IF;
```

didn't work.

Answer (score 10):

MySQL has function called `DEFAULT()`, which gets the default value from specified column.

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = DEFAULT(col);
```

[MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_default)

Comment: Well then you can clarify the question.

Comment: I did so in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

@JanTraenkner As far as I can tell, this is not possible. You can however make sure in your application code, that all columns are mentioned in your update statement and for those that do not have a value your use `NULL` as value. Then your trigger code is almost right, you just need to change it to

```
IF (NEW.column IS NULL) THEN
 SET NEW.column = value
END IF;
```

**Original answer:**

I understood your question like, "set column to default value, if I don't specify the column in an update statement (which updates other columns from that table)".

To check with `ISNULL()` or `col IS NULL` doesn't work here, because when you don't specify it in the update statement it simply isn't there. There's nothing to check for.

I wrote this little example script which makes it work like I understood the question.

```
drop table if exists defvalue;
create table defvalue (id int auto_increment primary key, abc varchar(255) default 'default');
insert into defvalue (id) values (null);
insert into defvalue (id, abc) values (null, 'not_default_value');
insert into defvalue (id, abc) values (null, 'another_not_default_value');

drop trigger if exists t_defval;
delimiter $$
create trigger t_defval before update on defvalue
for each row
begin
set @my_def_value = (select default(abc) from defvalue limit 1);
if (new.abc = old.abc) then
set new.abc = @my_def_value;
end if;
end $$
delimiter ;

select * from defvalue;

update defvalue set id = 99 where id = 1;

select * from defvalue;

update defvalue set id = 98 where id = 2;

select * from defvalue;
```

I also had to save the default value of the column in a variable first because the function needs to know from which table. Unfortunately one can't specify that as parameter, not even as `default(tablename.column)`.

All in all, please note, that this is rather a **proof of concept. I'd recommend to solve this on application layer, not database layer.** Having a trigger for this seems a bit dirty for me.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I meant. However, your code also sets the column to the default value if it is specified, but identical to the previous value.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what's the problem, please rephrase. If you do for example `update defvalue set id = 97, abc = 'new_value' where id = 3;` then the `new_value` will be set, not the default value.

Comment: Lets say you already have an entry in the table with id=3, abc = 'new_value' and you execute your update statement, then abc will be set to the default value (since NEW.abc = OLD.abc), instead of 'new_value'

Comment: I thought, that was what you're looking for. You don't specify an explicit value for column abc, so its value gets resetted to default. Please clarify your question with some examples of update statements and the desired result.

Comment: Sorry for not being more precise. But in the last example I do specify an explicit value for abc, it just happens to be identical to the value already in the database. However, the value gets reset to the default value.

Comment: Okay, understood the problem. As a quick shot I'd say it's not possible. You'd have to catch that in application code. It's a good idea anyway, I mean, why do you have different update statements anyway? And to expect different behaviour depending on what columns were specified and then what values those columns have and trying to catch that on database level is really a bit weird. Still, since I'm curious I'll have another look.

Comment: @JanTraenkner Updated my answer...Hope this helps, I'm sure it's your best bet.