# MySQL - trigger on before insert + if data already exists + enum column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a trigger that I though is quite easy and should work but it is not working.

Here is the (abstract) table structure:

```
PK_id    |    FK1_id    |    FK2_id    |    status
1        |    12        |    15        |    'ok'
```

`status` column is defined as `enum('ok', 'ok_2', 'not_ok') NUT NULL` with no default value.

The trigger should verify that a combination of both `FKx_id` values already exists and if yes it should set the `status` to 'ok_2', otherwise to 'ok' and if the `status` is set in the `INSERT INTO` it is not touched.

The trigger I have right now (only body!):

```mysql
BEGIN
    DECLARE cnt INT;
    SET cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `FK1_id` = NEW.FK1_id AND `FK2_id` = NEW.FK2_id);
    IF cnt > 0 AND NEW.status IS NULL THEN 
        SET NEW.status = 'ok_2';
    ELSEIF NEW.status IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.status = 'ok';
    END IF;
END
```

Unfortunately this trigger sets the `status` always to `'ok'` - please notice that the `status` is not part of the `INSERT` query (thus considered as `NULL`). I have previously tried this trigger body with the same result:

```mysql
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `FK1_id` = NEW.FK1_id AND `FK2_id` = NEW.FK2_id) > 0 AND NEW.status IS NULL THEN 
        SET NEW.status = 'ok_2';
    ELSEIF NEW.status IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.status = 'ok';
    END IF;
END
```

and also this (with the very same result):

```mysql
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `FK1_id` = NEW.FK1_id AND `FK2_id` = NEW.FK2_id LIMIT 1) AND NEW.status IS NULL THEN 
        SET NEW.status = 'ok_2';
    ELSEIF NEW.status IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.status = 'ok';
    END IF;
END
```

Can anyone tell me why the first condition is never met even if I am inserting the same `FKx_id` combination that is already present in the table?

**EDIT**: I switched the condition and the result is also the same - no 'ok_2' status set:

```mysql
BEGIN
    DECLARE cnt INT;
    SET cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `FK1_id` = NEW.FK1_id AND `FK2_id` = NEW.FK2_id);
    IF cnt = 0 AND NEW.status IS NULL THEN 
        SET NEW.status = 'ok';
    ELSEIF NEW.status IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.status = 'ok_2';
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Check if the `status` is defined as `status data_type default ''`? `Empty string` is not equal to `null`. `if( '' is not null, 'true', 'false' )` returns a `true`.

Comment: When defined as `default ''`, unless you intend to insert a value for the said field, it would be a *default value defined* on that field.

Comment: `status` has no default value thus when omitted in `INSERT` query it is considered `NULL`. If it wouldn't, then even the second condition wouldn't be met and even `'ok'` wouldn't be inserted. Or would it? The `status` is an `enum('ok', 'ok_2', 'not_ok')`...

Comment: Can you debug value of `cnt` after `SET cnt=...`? What is it returning?

Comment: If `cnt > 0` was `true` on the `IF` condition, it would have not entered into `ELSEIF`.

Comment: Yes, I can, and I did already, it is returning the count of rows containing the same `FKx_id` combination, which is either zero if that combination is not present or greater than zero if it is present.

Comment: I already had an extensive try checking if a value was given in a statement for a column while answering this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20938959/447489 Conclusion was, it's not possible. You can't check if something not existing is null, as weird as it sounds.

Comment: Yes. I just tried a sample trigger in my environment and the result was perfect. OP's issue is not found on repeated attempts.

Comment: @AmitGarg If you use `SET cnt = (SELECT ...)` it works well in MySQL procedural language - thus no need to `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

The problem was this declaration of the `status` column:

```
status enum('ok', 'ok_2', 'not_ok') NOT NULL
```

which leads into `status` being pre-filled with the first enum's value if the `status` is not set in the `INSERT` statement. So the solution is next trigger body:

```mysql
BEGIN
    DECLARE cnt INT;
    SET cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `FK1_id` = NEW.FK1_id AND `FK2_id` = NEW.FK2_id);
    IF cnt = 0 THEN 
        SET NEW.status = 'ok';
    ELSEIF NEW.status = 'ok' THEN
        SET NEW.status = 'ok_2';
    END IF;
END
```

Now if I do this insert for the first time

INSERT INTO table (FK_1, FK_2) VALUES (100, 150)

the status is `'ok'`, if I insert this for the second time

INSERT INTO table (FK_1, FK_2) VALUES (100, 150)

the status is `'ok_2'` and if I set the status explicitly like this:

INSERT INTO table (FK_1, FK_2, status) VALUES (100, 150, 'not_ok')

the status is `'not_ok'`.

**so, when working with enums that have no default value while are set as `NOT NULL` - do not expect them to be NULL on insert when omitted. The will be pre-filled probably with the first enums's value.**

Comment: @Ravinder If that isn't a reason to upvote, I don't know... ;)

Comment: Cool, not me. But worth as you published it.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but had a look at your profile. Member for 2 years, 9 months and just about 200 votes cast. That says it all, for me. I'll try to remember that, when I stumble over any of your answers, not that I mistakenly upvote you, oh my god. Anyway, no offense...

Comment: Com'on guys, my question wasn't about getting upvotes, but to find a solution to my problem. While the question was posted I did additional trigger debugging and found a solution. That' all, left it here for future reference and in case somebody may stumble upon same/similar problem :-) It's everyone's choice whether to (up|down)vote if voting even. I vote up everytime something seems interesting or helps solving my problem, even if not directly. But it's me. Other guys maybe upvotes only when really necessary... :-)